# Calculating total latitude/longitude of annotations in Swift 4 mapKit?

Tags: arrays, swift, annotations, mapkit

So I have a navigation application using the mapKit, and I have a button that allows the user to add multiple annotations if they would like.  I should add that they add these by searching for a location in a searchtable, and pressing it, creating the annotation, like normal maps apps.  My button allows them to add multiple.

1) How can I add the latitudes/longitudes of each annotation?  I was thinking something along the lines of a

```
let totalLatitude = mapView.annotations.reduce etc etc
```

Will this work?

2) What parameters should I use if it is a reduce?

3) How can I put it in a form that allows me to specify like mapView.annotations.coordinate.latitude etc etc?

4) I know you can't put .coordinate with .annotations... so is there another way? thanks

Comment: What does it mean to add the latitudes/longitudes of all your annotations? That doesn't seem like a meaningful value. Are you looking to calculate the total span of latitudes/longitudes of all the entered points? (The "footprint" of the points)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean you want the sum of the latitudes/longitudes of all annotations:

```
let totalLatitudes = mapView.annotations.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.coordinate.latitude }

let totalLongitudes = mapView.annotations.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.coordinate.longitude }
```

Comment: What does "total latitudes" or "total longitudes" mean though? Nothing, really.